# Linear barcode generation in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am looking for a free API for generating linear barcodes in iPhone. I had found one zxing library for generating barcodes but it generates only QR code.
Please suggest me a library for generating linear bar codes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this project easy to learn.

https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes

For a quick demonstration
There are several other barcode types this project renders, just make sure to import the header for your specific need.

Add the files from the Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes project into your Xcode project.

In the class you will use to help display the barcode

```
#import "UIImage-NKDBarcode.h"
#import "NKDEAN13Barcode.h"

-(void)showBarcode {
     NKDBarcode * nkdbarcode = [[NKDEAN13Barcode alloc] initWithContent:@"1234567890123"];
     UIImage * image = [UIImage imageFromBarcode:nkdbarcode];
     // assume barcodeIV is an outlet to an imageview
     [barcodeIV setImage:image];
}
```

Comment: ya, got it. Thanks Maudicus. One last question: what if I want to display the barcode number (like 1234567890123 here) beneath the barcode. Will I need to uncomment something? Can you please provide me the required code?

Comment: The Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes documentation states that feature is not supported.  Just place a label below your image and set the text dynamically

Answer (score 3):

## Avaible IOS 8.0 or Later

You can add this method and create linear barcode easily

```
+(CIImage*)generateBarcode:(NSString*)dataString{

CIFilter *barCodeFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CICode128BarcodeGenerator"];
NSData *barCodeData = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[barCodeFilter setValue:barCodeData forKey:@"inputMessage"];
[barCodeFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0] forKey:@"inputQuietSpace"];

CIImage *barCodeImage = barCodeFilter.outputImage;
return barCodeImage;
}
```

And you can use returning CIImage with UIImageView like;

```
self.imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage: [self generateBarcode:@"SOME STRING HERE"]];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and native solution without any third-party libraries !

Answer (score 0):

Just use any of the commonly-available barcode fonts.  Google for them, and use them like any other typeface.